# Marshalling ArgIterator to va_list

Tags: c#, interop, variadic-functions

So, I got an idea to try to p/invoke C functions that take `va_list`. I know how to p/invoke classic varargs functions (with `__arglist`), and as it seemed to me that `va_list` works just like an `ArgIterator`, I thought it might be possible to just pass it to the method:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int vswprintf(StringBuilder str, int length, string format, ArgIterator args);

public static int vswprintf(StringBuilder str, int length, string format, __arglist)
{
    return vswprintf(str, length, format, new ArgIterator(__arglist));
}

int len = 100;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
vswprintf(sb, len, "%s, %d", __arglist("test", 2));
```

It turns out that .NET actually recognizes this, because the following exception is thrown:

```
System.NotSupportedException
   in System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.MarshalToUnmanagedVaListInternal(IntPtr va_list, UInt32 vaListSize, IntPtr pArgIterator)
   in Program.vswprintf(StringBuilder str, Int32 length, String format, ArgIterator args)
   in Program.vswprintf(StringBuilder str, Int32 length, String format)
```

So, apparently, .NET knows what I am trying to do and has something that should do it:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), ForceTokenStabilization]
internal static extern void MarshalToUnmanagedVaListInternal(IntPtr va_list, uint vaListSize, IntPtr pArgIterator); //Reflector
```

The names of the arguments hint at the purpose, but the exception confuses me. Do I do the p/invoke wrong, or is this .NET marshalling method not finished?

Edit:
After a bit of a research, I've found the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/clrvarargs.cpp#L42) of this method and it seems it isn't possible to pass a normal string. So I've modified the code:

```
vswprintf(sb, len, "%d, %d", __arglist(1, 2));
```

But this throws an `AccessViolationException` (my favourite) instead! What's wrong now?

Comment: You can easily see the rules back today thanks to the CoreCLR source published on github.  Have a look-see in coreclr\src\vm\clrvarargs.cpp, VARARGS::MarshalToUnmanagedVaList() function.  You see it doing type-checking on the passed arguments.  Only simple blittable types that require no conversion can work.  Not strings, you'd have to use Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni().

Comment: @Hans Thanks, but even after trying a blittable primitive type, it still doesn't work. See the edit.